# React native text being cut off in nested Text components

Tags: react-native

I have a Text view nested inside another Text view, and the text is being cut off of the innermost Text view. Here is my view hierarchy:

```
<View style={this.props.style}>
    <Text style={styles.textStyle}>
      {this.paragraphTextHere()}      
      <Text onPress={this.performAction.bind(this) style={styles.sourceText}>
        &nbsp;[<Text
            style={{color: 'blue'}}>{sourceId}
          </Text>
        ]&nbsp;&nbsp;
      </Text>
    </Text>
  </View>
```

(The purpose of the `&nbsp;&nbsp;` is to enlarge the touch area of the pressable Text)

However, the text gets cut off, like this:

[image]

When I remove the `&nbsp;` the text is not cut off. However I need that there to enlarge the touch area of the Text.

I've tried changing both padding and margin properties on the both the inner and outer Text views, but nothing changes--it's like the Text component is immune to any change from padding/margin.

How can I add this extra touch area to the Text (to make the hit area bigger), without getting the text cut off?

Comment: i believe all the child `<Text>` components will conform to the parent `<View>` component's dimensions instead. have you considered enlarging the `<View>` dimensions?

Comment: Will try that, but the whole View itself is self sized because there is a variable paragraph of text.